# Creating Multiple PDF Files from Form

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, automation

i need some help with the code below, i got this code on a tutorial and it`s working fine for me, the point of this question is, the code below only generate 1 PDF from a constant PDF Form, using Cells "A2" and "B2". How can i make a Loop, so the code generate 1 PDF file based on each row from sheet with text?

Im providing the code below. I would be very grateful for the help and time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Write_to_pdf_form()

'declaring variables
Dim pdfApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim pdfDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim Support_doc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim pdffile
Dim wsDocs As Worksheet
Dim outputname


'declaring output path
pdffile = "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\Forms.pdf"
Dim pdf_form As AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp


'declaring fields
Dim num_doc As AFORMAUTLib.Field
Dim desc_doc As AFORMAUTLib.Field

Set pdfApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set pdfDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If pdfDoc.Open(pdffile, "") = True Then
pdfDoc.BringToFront
pdfApp.Show


'setting fields names
Set pdf_form = CreateObject("AFORMAUT.App")
Set num_doc = pdf_form.Fields("N")
Set desc_doc = pdf_form.Fields("descrição documento")

'setting fields values
num_doc.Value = Worksheets("docs").Range("A2").Value

desc_doc.Value = Worksheets("docs").Range("B2").Value


'setting output name of PDF
outputname = "Doc." & num_doc.Value & "-" & desc_doc.Value



Set Support_doc = pdfDoc.GetPDDoc


If Support_doc.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\" & outputname & ".pdf") Then

Debug.Print "Saved"
Else
Debug.Print "Failed to save the doc"

End If

pdfDoc.Close True
Support_doc.Close
pdfApp.Exit
Set num_doc = Nothing
Set desc_doc = Nothing

Set pdfDoc = Nothing
Set Support_doc = Nothing
Set pdfApp = Nothing



End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are starting with VBA, I would suggest you have a look at [this tutorial about loops in VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRhvKTgUIR8&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckV9rAM3yv8ym4pioIMA0UR&index=39&t=0s) or any of the ones available on the topic. This way you can learn how to do this by yourself. And after you've tried on your own, if you still face difficulties, feel free to come back to Stack Overflow to edit this question or create a new question detailing your progress and the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: Thx forthe help Mr. DecimalTurn, i would not say i`m a novice at VBA, but im defintily not an expert. I`ll look at the tutorial, thx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, using For Each, and some labels, i got it working just great.

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("docs").Range("A2:B500")


If cell.Value = "" Then
GoTo Line4
End If

    If cell.Column = 1 Then
    cell.Activate
        If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        num_doc.Value = ActiveCell.Value
        GoTo Line1
        End If
    End If

    
If cell.Column = 2 Then
    cell.Activate
        If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        GoTo Line1
        Else: desc_doc.Value = ActiveCell.Value
            If desc_doc.Value <> "" And num_doc.Value <> "" Then
            GoTo Line3
            End If
        End If
End If
    

 If desc_doc Or num_doc = "" Then
 GoTo Line4
 End If


  
    
                         
           
 Line3:

 outputname = "Doc." & num_doc.Value & "-" & desc_doc.Value


 Set Support_doc = pdfDoc.GetPDDoc

 If Support_doc.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\User\Documents\testesbulkpdf\" & outputname 
 & ".pdf") Then
 Debug.Print "Saved"
Else
Debug.Print "Failed to save the doc"
End If
    
Line1:
Next cell


Line4:

pdfDoc.Close True
Support_doc.Close
pdfApp.Exit
Set num_doc = Nothing
Set desc_doc = Nothing

Set pdfDoc = Nothing
Set Support_doc = Nothing
Set pdfApp = Nothing

End Sub
```